# Change the code for switch statement in C?

Tags: c

I have created this program to convert fahrenheit to celsius and vice versa now i want to convert this if-statement to switch statement, can someone please help me with that task.

```
int main(void) {

char condition; // Declare a variable.
float celsius, fahrenheit, temp;

printf("Enter Temp in either Celsius or Fahrenheit: \n"); scanf("%f", &temp); //Ask user to enter Temp.

printf("What type of conversion you want? (hint: 'C/c' for Celsius or 'F/f' for Fahrenheit) \n"); scanf(" %c", &condition);
if ( condition == 'f' || condition == 'F' ) {

    fahrenheit = ( temp * 1.8 ) + 32; //Calculates temp in Fahrenheit.

    printf("The temp in Fahrenheit is: %.2f", fahrenheit); //Displays result.

} else if ( condition == 'c' || condition == 'C' ) {

    celsius = ( temp - 32 ) / 1.8; //Calculate temp in Celsius.

    printf("The temp in Celsius is: %.2f",  celsius); //Displays result.
    }
}
```

Comment: Help you, probably. Do it for you, no.  Show us what you've tried and explain how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch(condition){
    case 'f': 
    case 'F':
        fahrenheit = ( temp * 1.8 ) + 32;
        printf("The temp in Fahrenheit is: %.2f", fahrenheit);
        break;

    case 'c':
    case 'C':
        celsius = ( temp - 32 ) / 1.8;
        printf("The temp in Celsius is: %.2f",  celsius);      
        break;     
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because a) you're doing his work for him and b) you have redundant code.

Comment: Downvoted because of what @JonathonReinhart said, and I wanted to see an animated unicorn.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(condition){
case 'f':case'F':
  //block
  break;
case 'c':case'C':
  //block
  break;
default:
  //error
}
```

Comment: Never seen this kind of formatting for multiple cases handling the same ... - did you run out of new-lines? ;-)

Comment: However 1+ for mentioning at least in the comment, that the `default` branch indicates something "abnormal".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
switch( condition ) 
{
    case 'c':
    case 'C':
        fahrenheit = ( temp * 1.8 ) + 32; //Calculates temp in Fahrenheit.
        printf("The temp in Fahrenheit is: %.2f", fahrenheit); //Displays result.
        break;
    case 'f':
    case 'F':
        celsius = ( temp - 32 ) / 1.8; //Calculate temp in Celsius.
        printf("The temp in Celsius is: %.2f",  celsius); //Displays result.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
switch(condition)
{
    case 'f':
    case 'F': 
               fahrenheit = ( temp * 1.8 ) + 32; //Calculates temp in Fahrenheit.
               printf("The temp in Fahrenheit is: %.2f", fahrenheit); //Displays result.
               break;
    case 'c':
    case 'C': 
               celsius = ( temp - 32 ) / 1.8; //Calculate temp in Celsius.
               printf("The temp in Celsius is: %.2f",  celsius); //Displays result.
               break;
    default: break;
}
```

**Logic behind**: Control flow continues until `break` statement is detected. So even if `condition='f'`, case of 'F' will be executed and then break. The same happens in the case of `c` and `C`.